# Getting the target value name in nested html tags in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I wanted to get the name inside the `<Menu.Item>` div through  `e.target` 
Here is the code:

```html
<Menu.Item as="a" value="PG Details" onClick={this.menuClick}>
  <Icon name="home" />
  PG Details
</Menu.Item>
```

And, here is the onClick function

```
menuClick = e => console.log(e.target.value);
```

I want to grab the `PG Details` from the event `e`

Please assist

Comment: What does `e.target.value` evaluate as currently?

Comment: which library are you using for `Menu.Item`

Comment: I'm using semantic-ui-react library and i'm getting `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [HTMLElement.innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

> The `innerText` property of the HTMLElement interface represents the "rendered" text content of a node and its descendants.
>   As a getter, it approximates the text the user would get if they highlighted the contents of the element with the cursor and then copied it to the clipboard.

```
e.target.innerText
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping out !